# Merge time series columns dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes and I give their structure.

```
dataset1 <- rbind.pages(lapply(filesjsonrformat,fromJSON))

dataset2 <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]",  
paste(readLines("filesrjsonformat2.jsonr"), collapse=",")))

str(dataset1)
data.frame':    772517 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ status               : chr  "OPEN" "OPEN" "OPEN" "OPEN" ...
 $ datejlc              : POSIXct, format: "2015-09-15 22:13:20" "2015-10-09 
 17:14:40" "2015-09-18 12:06:23" "2015-09-10 00:20:37" ...
 $ hour                 : int  23 18 13 1 1 19 16 12 15 9 ...
 $ date                 : chr  "2015-09-15" "2015-10-09" "2015-09-18" "2015-
 09-10" ...
 $ days                 : chr  "mardi" "vendredi" "vendredi" "jeudi" ...

str(dataset2)
'data.frame':   4416 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ status: chr  "ok" "ok" "ok" "ok" ...
 $ data  :'data.frame': 4416 obs. of  32 variables:
  .. ..$ year  : chr  "2015" "2015" "2015" "2015" ...
  .. ..$ tzname: chr  "Europe/Paris" "Europe/Paris" "Europe/Paris"  
  "Europe/Paris" ...
  ..$ utcdate   :'data.frame':  4416 obs. of  7 variables:
  .. ..$ mday  : chr  "31" "31" "31" "31" ...
  .. ..$ hour  : chr  "00" "00" "01" "01" ...
  .. ..$ min   : chr  "00" "30" "00" "30" ...
  .. ..$ mon   : chr  "08" "08" "08" "08" ...
  .. ..$ pretty: chr  "12:00 AM GMT on August 31, 2015" "12:30 AM GMT on  
  August 31, 2015" "1:00 AM GMT on August 31, 2015" "1:30 AM GMT on August  
  31, 2015" ...
  .. ..$ year  : chr  "2015" "2015" "2015" "2015" ...
  .. ..$ tzname: chr  "UTC" "UTC" "UTC" "UTC" ...
```

How can I merge them joining by date please even if their size are different? I tried to use UTC as time zone in both case

Thanks

Comment: Make a POSIXct `datejlc` column in `dataset2`, and then use `merge` or the appropriate `dplyr` `*_join` function.

Comment: Looks like one (with only 4416 observation might be every 30 minutes ) while the other is disordered but 100 times more plentiful. Are you sure you really want to merge by _date_???. Are you really ready for a combinatorial explosion when the Cartesian product is formed?

Comment: can you be more explicit alistaire plz?